# Unity UI Scale on different resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine

I hope someone can help me. I have created a game with unity 5 for the school assignment but im struggling with the main menu. The problem is that i place some text on the screen but when i change the resolution then everything is displayed differently. At least not how and where i would like them. I have already watched some tutorial but none of them helped me.

So this is the menu on small resolution.
[image: Picture 1]

And this is on big resolution
[image: Picture 2]

But i would like to display it on big resolution like this:
[image]

The structure is the following:

Canvas
-Render mode: screen space camera
-Pixel perfect on
-plane distance = 1
-Everything else is in default settings

Panel
-Stretch horizontally and vertically

ExitGamePanel
-Center Bottom
-Text (Exit Game) as child

OptionsPanel
-Center Bottom
-Text (Options) as child

I have tried many settings but none of the would work. If anyone has an idea or could get me a link for a good tutorial i would really appropriate that.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach `Canvas Scaler` to the `Canvas` if it is not attached already. And set it's `UI Scale Mode` to *Scale With Screen Size*.

[image]

Comment: Thanx. Actually I have tried that as well but i changed the resolution and it did not work. But now with default setting it seems to be working. Im going to do some more readings about these stuffs to get some understanding because it is working now but i want to understand as well how this works and why, etc. Anyway thank you so much again!!